# Adding a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in Aurelia

Tags: amazon-web-services, aurelia

When I try to access my API via the Aurelia frontend I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://[my aws API URL here]/auth.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403

This is my code:

```
 constructor(Aurelia, HttpClient) {

    HttpClient.configure(http => {
      http.withBaseUrl(config.baseUrl);
    });

    this.http = HttpClient;
    this.app = Aurelia;

    this.session = JSON.parse(localStorage[config.tokenName] || null);
  }

login(username, password) {

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.createRequest(config.apiUrl + '/auth', { username, password })
      .asPost()
      .withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      .withBaseUrl(config.baseUrl)
      .send()
      .then((response) => response.content)
      .then((session) => {
        localStorage[config.tokenName] = JSON.stringify(session);
        this.session = session;
        this.app.setRoot('app');
    });
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

It works fine in Postman.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a _response_ header, that the server you are trying to request data from has to send.

Comment: So, am I correct to say that my API (AWS API gateway) does send this header when the request comes from the Postman app, but not when the request comes from my local development server (localhost:9000)? Mind you that I'm all very new to this. ;)

Comment: You can determine that by checking the network log for the specific request in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: What is your API built in?  I'm using Slim, and had to add a CORS origin header to specifically allow my Aurelia app to access the API.  But yes -- it needs to be added to the API, not Aurelia.

Comment: _“So, am I correct to say that my API (AWS API gateway) does send this header when the request comes from the Postman app, but not when the request comes from my local development server (localhost:9000)?”_ – no, likely your API doesn’t send it at all. Postman doesn’t run in the browser (as far as I can see?), so it is not affected by this in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the 'Enable CORS' in the AWS API gateway interface, and deploying the API again. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!